# Add items to popup programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I need to create and add some items to a popup code-behind. It's easy to do this in XAML:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False">
    <DockPanel>
        //Items here
    </DockPanel>
 </Popup>
```

I think "Child" is where I need to add my items but I don't see any "Add", "Items", "Source" or "Content" inside. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
Popup myPopup= new Popup();
myPopup.Child // ... need to add items there
```

Comment: Have you tried to set for instance StackPanel as Child and then add items to this StackPanel?

Comment: Are the items to be added always the same? That is, the same kind of control with just different data? Or totally different controls determined at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Popup is a FrameworkElement and can have only one child (Child) => you cannot add multiple controls inside, but you can **set** Child to be any UIElement you want. For instance a DockPanel, and than use AddChild on the panel to add further controls.

```
myPopup.Child = new DockPanel();
```

Answer (score 5):

You would set the child of the PopUp to the DockPanel and then add children to the DockPanel.

Here is code that shows that:

```
   var popup = new Popup();
   var dockPanel = new DockPanel();
   popup.Child = dockPanel;
   dockPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox {Text = "First Child" });
   popup.IsOpen = true;
```